# Move a gameObject to another object after entering collision. Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very beginner in C# and Unity3D, so my question might be weird but please don't judge me. I have a trouble to figuring out what's wrong and why it doesn't work.

I have a ghost in the game, when I come closer to it, it has to move away from me. I have created collision around the ghost and added this script to it:

```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

public class MaidTriggeris : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject light;
    public GameObject sing;
    public GameObject ghost;
    public float speed;
    public GameObject target;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        light.SetActive(true);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnTriggerEnter(){
        light.SetActive (false);
        DestroyObject (sing);
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        ghost.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(ghost.transform.position, target.transform.position, step);
    }
}
```

Anyway, when I move in the collision box, everything works (it destroys game object "sing" and sets light to "false"), however it never moves gameObject's "ghost" position to another object "target". My speed is set to 5 and all objects are assigned.

Comment: Are you sure that ghost and target having different position of they are not parent child?

Comment: @Hanza Hasan I am sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are executing `Vector3.MoveTowards` only once so your `ghost` is moving only one step. What you need is to execute this in `Update` with help of any flag on in `Coroutine` under some condition.Like,

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MaidTriggeris : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject light;
    public GameObject sing;
    public GameObject ghost;
    public float speed;
    public GameObject target;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        light.SetActive(true);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnTriggerEnter(){
        light.SetActive (false);
        DestroyObject (sing);
        StartCoroutine("MoveGhost");            
    }

    IEnumerator MoveGhost(){
        while(Vector3.Distance(ghost.transform.position, target.transform.position) > 1.0f) // Change this value accordingly 
            {
                float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
                ghost.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(ghost.transform.position, target.transform.position, step);
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            }
    }
}
```

Above code snippet is not tested though. So make some tweaking if needed.